# Are there any examples of groups with a 4-regular cayley graph with an euler characteristic of 2?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

The motivation here is that I'm looking for a group that topologically (based on its Cayley Graph) behaves like a sphere, but algebraically is similar to the direct product of two cyclic groups (which have 4-regular Cayley graphs), but are toroidal, with an Euler characteristic of 0.

Comment: Like [these](http://weddslist.com/groups/cayley-plat/index.html) you mean?

Comment: Yes, however I wasn't specific enough in my original question -- I'm also looking for 4-regular Cayley graphs. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: On that page, there are diagrams corresponding to the cuboctahedron ($A_4$), small rhombicuboctahedron ($S_4$) and small rhombicosidodecahedron ($A_5$) as well as antiprisms from dihedral groups (which are semidirect products of cyclic groups). Do those count, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, those examples are what I'm looking for, I didn't see them at first -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are at least some examples, listed at this really great website http://weddslist.com/groups/cayley-plat/index.html .

In particular,

- $A_4$ has a Cayley graph that's the skeleton of the [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron).
- $S_4$ has a Cayley graph that's the skeleton of the [rhombicuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron).
- $A_5$ has a Cayley graph that's the skeleton of the [rhombicosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicosidodecahedron).
- The dihedral groups have Cayley graphs that are the skeletons (skeleta? *skeleton* doesn't *look* Latin...) of [antiprisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiprism). Even better, since you wanted groups "similar to the direct product of two cyclic groups," the dihedral groups are [semidirect products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $C_n \rtimes C_2$, which is hopefully "similar" enough to a direct product in the sense that you want!

It would be interesting to know what, if any, other examples exist.